# reading a file in delphi(handling files)

Tags: delphi

I want to extract an item matching this random
number(ran),(read
it from the file using tstringlist) and then show it in a memo1
if the random number is 5 it´s gonna read the line 5 so it´s
gonna be tarr[6] becacuse it starts reading from 0 right?

```
unit handlingfiles;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, 
Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
const
n=10;
type
TStringArray=array[1..n]of string;

var
tarr:TStringArray;


procedure save(var tarre: TStringArray);
begin
tarr[1]:='hi';
tarr[2]:='bye';
tarr[3]:='how are you?';
tarr[4]:='whatsapp';
tarr[5]:='facebook';
tarr[6]:='instagram';
tarr[7]:='twitter';
tarr[8]:='youtube';
tarr[9]:='twitch';
tarr[10]:='google';

end;


procedure SaveArrayToFile(var tarre: TStringArray);
var
  index: Integer;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    for index:= Low(tarr) to High(tarr) do
    begin
      sl.Append(tarr[index]);
    end;
    sl.SaveToFile('questions.txt');
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;



procedure read(var tarre: TStringArray);
var
ran:integer;
begin
ran:=random(10)+1;
//here i want to extract an item matching this random 
number(read 
it from the file using tstringlist) and then show it in a memo1
if the random number is 5 it´s gonna read the line 5 so it´s 
gonna be tarr[6] becacuse it starts reading from 0 right?//
end;






procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
tarre: TStringArray;
begin
save(tarre);
SaveArrayToFile(tarre);
read(tarre);
end;

end.
```

Comment: You first write you use a ``TStringList``, but in code you use an ``array of string`` with fixed size! A ``TStringList`` is only used to save data to a file.

Comment: In your real application, is the array size small like in your example, or do you have thousands or millions of items? If it is small, then a TStringList is OK like in @MBo answer below. If it is large, then you could optimize the process using a database with an index, or make simple file but with fixed length record so that direct access is easy. If you tell us more about what are the requirements, you'll get a better answer. Edit your question to add the information.

Comment: You just need to learn to debug and some self sufficiency. Editing the Q to ask a different question isn't how we roll here.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the next example. Perhaps it does all that you need:

```
procedure TForm1.Button16Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add('a');
    sl.Add('bb');
    sl.Add('ccc');
    sl.Add('dddd');
    sl.Add('eeeee');
    sl.Add('ffffff');
    sl.Add('ggggggg');
    sl.Add('hhhhhhhh');
    sl.SaveToFile('test.txt')
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button17Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  s: string;
  ix: Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromFile('test.txt');

    //don't forget to call  Randomize once - for example, inside OnCreate

    //note usage of REAL list range to get existing string

    ix := Random(sl.Count);
    s := sl[ix];
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: My answer adresses initial version of question  - saving string set, reading it, choosing random item. Question did not contain information about need of searching, so please restore it's previous state. You can ask another question (and formulate it thoroughly)